# How to enforce license check on each .jsp page on spring mvc webapplication?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

We are developing a web application with Spring MVC and rest based conrollers. we have already implemented Authentication using spring security. Now this product should run with a valid license. This implementation is done and before webapp starts up we have this check to see whether product is licensed or not. If not user can upload license file and they can start use the product.

Once they start using the product, say after few days license might expire (of course, starting of server will catch this, but if there is no server re-start then they can happily use ever after expiry). So I want to have check on each request, whether the product is licensed (just like isAuthenticated()) or not. If not authenticated, i can redirect to License upload page.

Any ideas / pointers are appreciated.

```
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <beans:bean id="mySuccessHandler" class="com.cavirin.security.MySavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler" />
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider ref="localAuthenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <request-cache ref="authenticationRequestCache" />
        <form-login login-page="/"      
            authentication-success-handler-ref="successHandler"
            authentication-failure-url="/rest/login/reAuthenticate" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/rest/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />
    </http>

    <beans:bean id="successHandler"
        class="com.cavirin.security.MySavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/rest/login/checkUser" />
    </beans:bean>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check on every request you could just add a filter to your app. But that would be very annoying for users who were half-way through doing something when they get redirected to the license page. It also seems quite inefficient. As an alternative, you could add an `AuthenticationProvider` which just checks when someone logs in and denies authentication otherwise.

Comment: Before authentication, we do have check for validLicense. Yes. As you mentioned it could be inefficient, but I want to add  this just to avoid over use of product after expiry of license after logged-in. Could you please tell me how can i add another filter. Edited my question with few code snippets as I have already used "DelegatingFilterProxy".

Comment: I added a filter (public class LicenseCheckFilter implements Filter {...}, but how can i throw a custom exception, say LicenseExpiredException?

Comment: You can use more than one instance of `DelegatingFilterProxy` if you really need to delegate to a Spring bean. Or you can just add it as a standard filter in your `web.xml`. I don't see why you need an exception - just redirect from the filter.

Comment: I need to redirect to the license upload page with a message saying that "the license is expired"(-LicenseExpiredException)

Comment: So just call redirect with the URL you want to go to. You don't need to throw an actual Java exception to do that.

Comment: In that case, how the user will know that license has expired? Why I ask this is, when user authentication fails, we throw AuthenticationException which comes from spring security authentication provider. Will I not be able to implement the same with Servlet Filters?

Comment: You can just print a message to tell them. What's the difference? Why use an exception when you don't need one?

Comment: I did add Filter and if not valid license, then i redirect to a license upload page as like this. '((HttpServletResponse)response).sendRedirect("licenseUpload.jsp");' But I get redirect loop error. Is it something that I already have spring security in place? sorry for troubling, But not getting clear idea.

Comment: I resolved this. In fact, now I have complete idea how all these fit together after reading for 2days. I added custom-filter as you suggested on the authentication http and resolved it. Thanks for the help.